# Можно ли в ncurses добавить прокрутку?

Tags: c, ncurses

Можно ли добавить прокрутку, не одностороннюю, а как в обычном терминале, и вниз и вверх.

Answer (score 2):

Полный [материал](https://docstore.mik.ua/manuals/ru/lpg/node8.html#SECTION009130000000000000000) по библиотеке:

`int scrollok(win, bf)` Если `TRUE`, текст в окне `win` будет прокручен вверх на одну строку, когда курсор находится в правом нижнем углу и напечатан символ. Если `FALSE`, то курсор остается на прежней позиции.

При включенном `scrollok(...)` содержимое окна может быть прокручено при помощи нижеследующих функций. Замечание: оно будет прокручено и в случае, если вы напечатаете новую строку, находясь в последней строке окна, поэтому будьте осторожны со `scrollok(...)`.)

`int scroll(win)` Эта функция прокрутит окно (и строки в структуре данных) на одну строку вверх.

`int scrl(n)` и `int wscrl(win, n)` Эти функции прокрутят окно `stdscr` или `win` вверх или вниз, в зависимости от целого `n`. Если `n` положительное, произойдет прокрутка окна на `n` линий вверх, если `n` отрицательное на `n` линий вниз.

`int setscrreg(t, b)` и `int wsetscrreg(win, t, b)` Устанавливают программную область прокрутки.